# File Preview for SharedFolder indexed through Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We are crawling a sharedfolder through Sharepoint 2016.
Crawled files are searchable from SharePoint but we are not able to make a preview.Can someone please help us on it

Answer (score 0):

It's by design. 
The preview functionality in out-of-the-box SharePoint 2013 provides an excellent preview of documents that is located within SharePoint. But no preview 
is provides on content residing on file shares.